# Seeking help regarding uploading images to own dropbox without login screen (without linking a view controller)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using my own dropbox account for uploading/downloading user's images in iOS app and therefore, don't want to show login screen to users (as I am using my own dropbox). But, getting error (code 401) while uploading/downloading files, even though I have app key, secret and access token as well.

If I do it by showing login screen (by linking a view controller), it works. But my requirement is to authenticate by access token.

Any help, would be very much appreciated..

Below is the piece of code:

```
DBSession *dbSession = [[DBSession alloc]
                        initWithAppKey:kAppKey
                        appSecret:kAppSecret
                        root:kDBRootDropbox]; // either kDBRootAppFolder or kDBRootDropbox
[dbSession updateAccessToken:kAppAccess accessTokenSecret:kAppSecret forUserId:@"<userid>"];
dbSession.delegate=self;
[DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];
[DBRequest setNetworkRequestDelegate:self];
```

And while initiating DBRestClient:

```
_client = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
_client.delegate = self;
```

And upload functionality code:

```
NSString *filename = [self userProfileImagePath];

if (filename) {
    NSString *localPath = [self imagePathForName:filename];

    // Upload file to Dropbox
    NSString *destDir = @"/";
    [self.client uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
}
```

Comment: First, it's worth noting that this strategy of using a single account in a client side app like this isn't reccomended. There's some more discussion here: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=116098 That said though, this is the basic idea of how you would do this. Are you sure the access token you're using is valid though? A 401 would indicate it isn't.

Comment: I also like to do the same thing with one of the projects I'm working on but ends up with the same issues with Viren. :(